# Eigenvalues & eigenvectors of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a couple of questions regarding eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}4 & 2 \\ 5 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, $\mathbf{u}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\-5\end{pmatrix},\mathbf{v}=-2\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{w}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$

---

**1.** How would I be able to show that *u* is an eigenvector of **A** as well as finding the corresponding eigenvalue?

**2.** How would I be able to tell if *v* is an eigenvector of **A**? And *w* is an eigenvector of **A**?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Keep in mind the definition of an eigenvector:

- $v$ is an eigenvector of the matrix $A$ if $Av=\lambda v$, for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

**Question 1**

$Av=\begin{pmatrix}4&2\\5&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2\\-5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4\cdot2+2\cdot-5\\5\cdot2+1\cdot-5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2\\0\end{pmatrix}$

Since there is no $\lambda$ for which $Av=\lambda v$, $v$ is **not** an eigenvector of $A$.